# Use of words like "wanna", "gonna"

Tags: discussion

I am not particularly happy about the employment of words of this kind in questions, and particularly not in the title of questions. I was almost inclined to downvote this question [Somebody has posted a link to my profile in twitter. Could you tell me what he wants to say?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9974/somebody-post-a-link-of-my-profile-in-twitter-could-you-tell-me-what-he-wanna-sa) for that reason. I'd like to take advice on the point, though, given that the poster may not be a native speaker of English.

Am I being perhaps a little priggish; should I downvote, or edit, perhaps, or just leave a tactful comment?

Comment: @Jasper Loy, quite so. That's why I asked; the OP lists his location as 'Mars', which suggests he is not a native speaker.

Comment: I wanna, you wanna, but he wants to - it doesn't contract for me (with my dialect, anyway) no matter how informal I choose to be...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, at 2k rep you are part of the editor class and should be able to edit the post to whip it into shape -- assuming it is worth salvaging in the first place, of course.

Comment: thank you. I have cleaned up the post a little.

Comment: I disagree if the edit is 'silent' (like the one in question); others reading the thread later on will miss the opportunity to learn that 'wanna' is slang. I think the edit must be accompanied by a comment explaining "wanna changed to want to because XYZ". IMHO, I find silent edits very annoying for this very reason, I often say to myself "Hmmm, I wonder why that was edited?". The same logic applies to downvotes without comments; they might be obvious to the downvoter, but not necessarily to others, especially in a multi-cultural environment like this where misunderstandings are rife.

Comment: @smirkingman, good point. I didn't think of that. In future, I'll take care to state the changes and the reasons for the changes.

Comment: In this particular case, the asker did not know and was happy to be told that wanna was not proper English